# How to convert UTC timezone to CET timezone in graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Am tried with this piece of code

```
var Option = new List<Option>()
            {
                 new QueryOption("startDateTime", filterStartDate.ToLongDateString()),
                 new QueryOption("endDateTime", filterEndDate.ToLongDateString()),
                 new HeaderOption("Prefer","outlook.timezone=\"Central European Time\"")
            };
```

but am getting the bad request error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could please add more code? It's not clear which endpoint you call. Are filterStartDate and filterEndDate in UTC?

Comment: could you pls try `Central European Standard Time` instead of `Central European Time`?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 ideas on your scenario, the first is that, according to the [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request), you can add `Prefer` request header like this if you used Graph SDK.

```
var events = await graphClient.Me.Events
    .Request()
    .Header("Prefer","outlook.timezone=\"Pacific Standard Time\"")
    .Select("subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location")
    .GetAsync();
```

By the way, the time zone you used is `Central European Time` but it's not supported by graph api. Per my searching, only `Central European Standard Time` can be found.

In general, the timeZone property can be set to any of the time zones [currently supported by Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11), as well as the additional time zones [supported by the calendar API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0#additional-time-zones).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct time zone is `Central Europe Standard Time` not `Central European Time`.

If you are calling [calendar view events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` must be represented in ISO 8601 format.

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("startDateTime", filterStartDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o")),
    new QueryOption("endDateTime", filterEndDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"))
    new HeaderOption("Prefer","outlook.timezone=\"Central Europe Standard Time\"")
};

var calendarView = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.CalendarView
    .Request(queryOptions)
    .GetAsync();
```